# Bundler doesn't want to install hpricot on Windows XP with Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, bundle, bundler, hpricot

I develop on a Windows machine but deploy to Debian.  Trying to use hpricot with Rails 3 app. I can get the gem to install using :

```
gem install hpricot --platform=mswin32
```

But when I do this in the bundle file - it keeps throwing an error (I think it's trying to install the wrong version of hpricot (not windows specific)

```
group :production do
   gem "hpricot", "0.8.3"
end

group :development, :test do
   gem "hpricot", "0.8.3", :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]
end
```

This is from another question here on stackoverflow - but it's not working for me.

Any ideas?

P.S.:

Windows XP sp3 with Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 3.0.3 with bundler 1.0.7

**EDIT**

Forgot to paste my error:

```
bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
which: no sudo in (.;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.6.5-Q16;C:\ruby\Ruby187\bin;C:\Program Files\ActiveState Komodo Edit 6\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\e\cmd;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;c:\tools;C:\gnuwin32\bin;C:\tools\wkhtmltopdf;C:\Python31;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin; c:\program files\videolan\vlc;C:\Program Files\SMPlayer\mplayer;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;c:\ruby\jruby-1.5.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Shoes\0.r1514\..)
Using rake (0.8.7)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.3)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.4.2)
Using activemodel (3.0.3)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.1)
Using rack-mount (0.6.13)
Using rack-test (0.5.6)
Using tzinfo (0.3.23)
Using actionpack (3.0.3)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.1)
Using treetop (1.4.9)
Using mail (2.2.10)
Using actionmailer (3.0.3)
Using arel (2.0.4)
Using activerecord (3.0.3)
Using activeresource (3.0.3)
Using bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
Using bundler (1.0.7)
Using cancan (1.5.0)
Using haml (3.0.24)
Using compass (0.10.6)
Using warden (1.0.3)
Using devise (1.1.5)
Installing hpricot (0.8.3) Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
with native extensions C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

C:/ruby/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for stdio.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/ruby/Ruby187/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/hpricot-0.8.3/ext/fast_xs/gem_make.out
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:225:in `install'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from C:/ruby/Ruby187/bin/bundle:19
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @theIV, please see EDIT in the question - there is no space to paste here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had similar problems with bundler and Windows and one thing to check is that the specific version is available for both Windows and Linux/ruby native systems.

It may also be a good idea to do a bundle install on your deployment machine first, and then bring the Gemfile.lock file over to your Windows development box.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). It's very similar to Hpricot but is actively maintained and is faster.

Comment: I need to use hpricot cause it's a dependency in another library ( specifically haml scaffolding for devise)  , otherwise I would stick with nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no bundler expert, and far from a "Ruby in Windows-land" expert, but just from doing a little bit of research the `platforms` flag that you are trying to use in your Gemfile doesn't seem to be valid. The only information I could find on the topic was the following issue on the bundler github page https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/issue/663. Hope this helps.

Comment: theIV - actually not true  http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html . Ctrl+F for platforms

Comment: @Nick Gorbikoff thanks for teaching me something I didn't know :)

Comment: well as I understand from issues on github, this was added as of version 0.9. but I might be wrong.